# What is exact meaning of UTPATTI(उत्पत्ती), STITHI(स्तिथी) AND LAYA(लय)

Tags: vishnu, shiva, puranas, brahma, trinity

As we know the works of trimurti.

1. Lord Brahma's work is UTPATTI(उत्पत्ती).
2. Lord Vishnu's work is STITHI(स्तिथी).
3. Lord Shiva's work is LAYA(लय).

   I want to know what are the exact meanings of those word i.e UTPATTI(उत्पत्ती), STITHI(स्तिथी) AND LAYA(लय).

   As I know Lord Brahma is writing future of every soul. Lord Vishnu is protecting Dharma. and in some cases even Lord Shiva is also protecting Dharma. Like Lord Shiva took an incarnation as Adi Shankaracharya to protect dharma out of request of other God. We have many examples of Lord Vishnu taking an incarnation to protect Dharma.

   If Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva are protecting Dharma then what is exact nature of their work. I'm trying to search exact meaning of those 3 words. In other words, What are the exact works of Trimurtis?

Comment: UTPATTI = is creation. Vishnu = preservation.. Shiva = Destroy the Universe. 
These are the meaning of those words.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS I know that. Creation, Preservation and Destroy are the work of trimurti. Creation would began at the beginning of the Kalpa and destruction would be at the end of Kalpa. So for whole time only Lord Vishnu is active and other 2 are idol. I don't think so. This is creating a confusion in my mind.